# List.indexOf() with custom equals() of my class return -1

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand why ArrayList.indexOf() returns -1?

I created a simple class in which I implemented custom equals so that I could compare instances of a class with a string.

```
public class Currency {
    final private String code;
    final private String unicodeHex;
    final private String name;

    public Currency(String code, String unicodeHex, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.unicodeHex = unicodeHex;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return unicodeHex;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null) return false;
        if (o instanceof Currency) {
            Currency currency = (Currency) o;
            return code.equals(currency.code);
        } else if (o instanceof String) {
            String currency = (String) o;
            return code.equals(currency);
        } else return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(code);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Currency{" +
                "code='" + code + '\'' +
                ", unicodeHex='" + unicodeHex + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Now I need to find an instance of the class in the ArrayList.

```
List<Currency>  currencies = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new Currency("USD","0024","United States Dollar"),
                new Currency("EUR","20ac","Euro Member Countries")));

Log.d(TAG, currencies.toString());
Log.d(TAG,Integer.toString(currencies.indexOf("USD")));
```

```
2019-02-13 15:41:50.082 D/CurrencySelector: [Currency{code='USD', unicodeHex='0024', name='United States Dollar'}, Currency{code='EUR', unicodeHex='20ac', name='Euro Member Countries'}]
2019-02-13 15:41:50.082 D/CurrencySelector: -1
```

I am getting: **-1**

But:

```
Currency currency = new Currency("USD","0024","United States Dollar");

Log.d(TAG,Boolean.toString(currency.equals("USD")));
```

```
2019-02-13 15:41:50.082 D/CurrencySelector: true
```

the equals returns **true** as it should.

**ArrayList.indexOf** uses equals as it should:

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (elementData[i]==null)
                    return i;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: `currency.equals("USD")` returns `true` but `"USD".equals(currency)` will **not** return `true`.

Comment: Your equals is not following the equality contract since string.equals(currency) is false

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `currency.equals("USD")` may return `true` (due to your implementation), `"USD".equals(currency)` will never return `true`, since it uses the `equals` implementation of the `String` class, which requires the compared instance to be of type `String`.

Therefore, `currencies.indexOf("USD")` will return `-1`, since `o.equals(elementData[i])` calls `String`'s `equals`, and `elementData[i]` is not a `String`.

Comment: This is what happens. List.indexOf uses the equals method of the input. Also I would like to mention that equals should NEVER compare different objects and return true.

Comment: @kevintjuh93 what else would you compare? identical objects?

Comment: @Eran Thanks! Did not notice this. In my case, I can use: currencies.indexOf(new Currency("USD",null,null));
But I wanted a more beautiful implementation :)